# How can I add router link in datatable render in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dt-basic-example').dataTable({
        scrollY: 400,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: true,
        fixedColumns:
        {
            leftColumns: 0
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                title: 'Acciones',
                orderable: false,
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return `<a [routerLink]="['/home]" title='Editar'></a>`;
                },
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

This is my js file where I fill the datatable, and I need to put a link in a datatable column with some data in it.

But, the routerlink doesn't works

Comment: you're relying on jquery to inject dynamic values inside Angular... why not use angular for this?

Comment: so... sorry for my mess, but how can I do that?

Comment: create a minimal stackblitz of your angular code... update the question by specifying what you intend to do... that'll make it much easier to help... as it is, your question is too broad

Comment: Simply you can't at least not with jQuery due to angular does not know any DOM changes jQuery did.

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with this style, but you might have better luck creating a click event that then triggers the router.